# Trying to embed python into tinycc, says python symbols are undefined

Tags: python, c, compilation

I've literally spent the past half hour searching for the solution to this, and everything involves GCC. What I do here works absolutely fine with GCC, however I'm using TinyCC, and this is where I'm getting confused. First the code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(\"Hello World!\")");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I then call tcc like so:

```
tcc -o tinypyembed.exe tiny.c -IC:\Python26\include -LC:\Python26\libs -lpython26
```

It then becomes a big fat jerk and spits out

```
tcc: undefined symbol 'Py_Initialize'
tcc: undefined symbol 'PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
tcc: undefined symbol 'Py_Finalize'
```

I'm totally at my wits end and really do appreciate it if anyone knows what's up.

After asking a friend to try this out I have discovered that it is in fact a windows issue. May this stay here as a warning to anyone else who may try tinycc with python on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use `tiny_impdef.exe` to create a `.def` file for the Python DLL?

Comment: Well what do you know! :D Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 2):

Full solution for Windows:

1. tiny_impdef as per bk1e's advice

   `tiny_impdef.exe c:\WINDOWS\system32\python25.dll`
2. add python25.def (or python26.def) to compilation list

   `tcc tiny.c python25.def -IC:\Python25\include -LC:\Python25\libs -lpython25`

   (replace 25 with 26 for Python2.6)